# Levensthein logic to get all the string with minimum difference

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

Suppose i have a datframe with values

```
Mtemp:
-----+
code |
-----+
Ram  |
John |
Tracy|
Aman |
```

i want to compare it with dataframe
M2:

```
------+
code  |
------+
Vivek |
Girish|
Rum   |
Rama  |
Johny |
Stacy |
Jon   |
```

i want to get result so that for each value in Mtemp i will get maximum 2 possible match in M2 with Levensthein distance 2.

i have used

```
tp<-as.data.frame(amatch(Mtemp$code,M2$code,method = "lv",maxDist = 2))
tp$orig<-Mtemp$code
colnames(tp)<-c('Res','orig')
```

and i am getting result as follow

```
Res  |orig  
-----+-----
3    |Ram
5    |John
6    |Tracy
4    |Aman
```

please let me know a way to get 2 values(if possible) for every Mtemp string with Lev distance =2

Comment: The `adist` function in base R will calculate the edit distance. You can use this result to pull off the minimum two observations.